# What would Alta California look like in 1900, 1950, and today if the Mexican-American War never happened?

Tags: alternate-history

Let’s say that the Mexican-American War never happened. Texas still joins the United States in 1845 and its borders are settled to contain only the undisputed portion of the Republic. What would Alta California look like in 1900, 1950, and today if the Mexican-American War never happened? How would world events have occurred without the war?

Comment: what other events did happen/not happen? Was there an american civil war? Was there a WW1 and WW2? Was Mexico on the side of the Axis or Allies in WW2 (if it happended)?

Answer (score 3):

First I’m going to go over the repercussions of not having the Mexican American War

The Mexican-American War was a turning point in American history, as it lead to the US having access to the Pacific Ocean, and the war was critical to the start of the American Civil War.

The American Civil War was fundamentally based on the issue of whether new states admitted to the Union would be slave or free. These new states came from the territories taken by conquest during the Mexican Civil War. No new states means no legal battles over their status, and therefore the Planter Aristocracy in the South will not feel as existentially threatened. The slaver’s fear was that the new free states would outnumber slave states, and would call a constitutional convention to make slavery federally illegal.

So without the Mexican-American War you could see slavery’s existence in the US given a few more years, maybe a decade until the Civil War kicks off anyway or something else breaks. If the US is in civil war later than it could significantly impact its relations with England and France, which could have negative repercussions for all three powers just a few decades later in WWI. The US would be much poorer without the riches of the west coast, it would be even less popular in Europe as a slave economy, and it would be reeling from a later civil war or a costly slave manumission program that would prevent it from taking part in WWI.

Although the US joined very late in the war, it still played a very important part in that it pressured (and helped halt) the Germans to go on the Great Spring Offensive. Without American reinforcements French and British morale was running on fumes, and the Germans could have very well held out, possibly being able to negotiate a much more favorable armistice.

A better deal for Germany could very well prevent the rise of Hitler and the Second World War. Or it could still happen nonetheless.

WWII would also get very interesting. Without a presence on the West Coast, the US would not be a significant threat to the Japanese; they wouldn’t control Hawaii or Alaska. This means that the Japanese will not go to war with the US, and would have a much better chance at achieving their goal of East Asian hegemony, as they wouldn’t have to fight the US Navy at all. It’s also not implausible to think that Mexico might provide oil to Japan rather than embargoing them.

With Japan unhindered, the Soviets would still have to keep their Siberian divisions in the East. This means Zhukov won’t be fighting the Germans.

A poorer US also had severe  consequences  for the Allies. Lend Lease was critical to the allied war effort, with even Nikita Khrushchev admitting that American aide was invaluable during the war. Now, I’m not saying the Axis would win, but if the Soviets are stretched thinner and have less equipment then the war could very well be extended for months or years. Millions would die. The entire dynamic of the Cold War would be different.

Now for the rest:

**In 1900**

Alta California would far less populated and developed than it is in our timeline (OTL). This is because there would almost certainly not be a Gold Rush as we saw in OTL California.

Mexico, like almost all former colonies of Spain inherited a mercantilist view of natural resources that valued the government and elite’s unmitigated access in contrast to the Anglo free market view. You can see this mindset in action to this very day with Pemex, Mexico’s state run Oil Company. It’s absurdly corrupt and could be much more efficient. Gold being discovered in Alta California would result in Mexican elites owning the rights to all the gold and most likely using some encomienda strategy of cajoling California natives or peasants to extract it for them.

Mexico never brought in immigrants like the United States did, and thus you wouldn’t have anywhere near the number of enterprising people going out and making their fortunes on the west coast.

This would actually be much better for the Native Americans of Alta California, simply compare the numbers of Native Americans to Indios in Mexico. Mexicans liked to fuck the natives, Americans liked to fuck over the natives.

Washington and Oregon would still have the fur trade, but the fur trade would likely be totally dominated by non Mexican entities like the British Hudson’s Bay Company.

In short Alta California would be less developed and more native.

**In 1950**

The selling of petroleum, timber, agricultural products and metals to the Empire of Japan is a major aspect of the economy. It is still ultimately an agrarian and extractive economy, and exponentially poorer than the West Coast OTL, consider the GDP of say Chile in comparison to California to get an idea.

**Today**

Alta Californians just can’t get enough of their Japanese Smartphones built with slave labor in Manchuria

Comment: If Germany had not capitulated in WW1, then the [treaty of Brest-Litovsk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Brest-Litovsk) would have remained in force. There would have been no Poland, no Baltic republics, tthe most interesting parts of Ukraine would no longer be part of the Russian Empire...

Comment: The US would still have had access to the Pacific without the Mexican-American War: see e.g. Lewis & Clark.  Emigrants would still have gone west, perhaps using more northerly routes.  Gold seekers would still have flocked to California, and in all probability would still have declared independence from Mexico.  Perhaps California would have stayed independent, then annexed the silver-mining areas of northern Nevada, causing a Mexican-Californian War...

Comment: @jamesqf very good point and an egregious oversight on my part. Washington state would still be part of the US and would therefore provide pacific access in this timeline. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @AlexP Good point on Brest-Litovsk. Keeping those borders would completely alter the history of all Eastern Europe and the Second World War